# iOS 13: UITextField with LeftView spacing issue - Xcode 11

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios13, xcode11, leftview

iOS 12.0 with Xcode 10.0

[image]

iOS 13.0 with Xcode 11.0

[image]

I have taken custom LeftView with image and label for adding LeftView in UITextField. I have set all the needed constraints also but still I am facing issues of LeftView width spacing. In old Xcode and iOS it was working well but after new Xcode and iOS there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem fixed by adding constraints.
Make sure had set UIImageView and UILabel width constraints and margins with other views, like:

```
H:|-0-[image(==40)]-0-[label(==70)]-0-|
```

hoping this help.