# iOS 13 UISearchController Bookmark

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

In iOS 13 my custom UISearchController bookmark image stretches and is not sizing to fit properly.

In iOS 12.x the image fits nicely in the search bar:

[image: iOS 12 image]

But in iOS 13 I get the below look:

[image: iOS 13 Image]

The image is being set the same way in both versions (same version of the app running on both devices)

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
    self?.txtSearchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "barcode_image"), for: .bookmark, state: .normal)
}
```

I've tried setting the contentMode of the searchBar and all subviews to .scaleAspectFit but no luck. I also tried looping through all the subviews looking for UIButton but didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be due to the image size.

In iOS 12 the image was being resized to fit but in iOS 13 that was not the case. Adding proper 1x, 2x, and 3x sizes resolved the issue.

Comment: Identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58167613/ios-13-uitextfield-with-leftview-spacing-issue-xcode-11

Comment: And Apple actually called this out in one iteration of the release notes (no longer available?): "Starting in iOS 13, the implementation of `leftViewRect(forBounds:)` and `rightViewRect(forBounds:)` now ask the view for its `systemLayoutSizeFitting(:)`. To achieve the previous behavior when linking against and running on iOS 13, add explicit sizing constraints on the view, wrap it in a plain UIView, or subclass the view and implement `systemLayoutSizeFitting(:)`."